# how to programatically modify a CheckBoxPreference view

Tags: android, android-preferences

How can I change the view of a CheckBoxPreference at runtime?

Specifically, I'd like to change a CheckBoxPreference summary depending on whether the user has checked the box or not.

If it were a normal view, I could do something like:

```
view1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.idView1);
view1.setText("some text");
```

But a CheckBoxPreference has no id, so I don't know how to get a "handle" to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have an answer to my own question.  The key is to use `findPreference` in a `PreferenceActivity`, as follows:

```
public class MyPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity{

    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener prefListener;
    private CheckBoxPreference pref;

    @Override    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        pref = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference(res.getString(R.string.keyAccount));
        pref.setSummary("something");

        //-- preference change listener
        prefListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(){
             public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key){  
                 if (key.equals(somekey)){                                       
                     pref.setSummary("something new");

                 }
             }
        };
        preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefListener);     
    }
```

This is tested and works.

Comment: What if you use a PreferenceFragment? How do you get the views?

Comment: where are you unregistering the listener?

Answer (score 1):

You should use (in XML layout file):

```
android:summaryOff
android:summaryOn
```

Answer (score -2):

You can set id to CheckBoxPreference using `android:id` in xml like code below

```
<CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="pref_boot_startup"
        android:title="Auto start"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:id="@+id/my_CheckBoxPref"
        />
```

To retrieve you can use

```
CheckBoxPreference check = (CheckBoxPreference)findViewById(R.id.my_CheckBoxPref);
```

Comment: Thanks Sunil, but I think you might be mistaken.  "android:id" is not an allowable xml attribute of CheckBoxPreference, so it is not recognized.

Comment: OK, I've confirmed that there is no "android:id" attribute for CheckBoxPreference, so this answer cannot be used.