# Android A way to trigger onSharedPreferenceChange() for a/all preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

1. I load a new set of settings by reading a text file and parsing it.
2. For each setting I found there I extract the value and update the corresponding preference (whether it is CheckPreference, ListPreference or EditTextPreference).
3. All this is done from the settings fragment. Meaning the preference screen is in view while I make the changes.
4. Because I change the vaules programatically (`editor().commit`), onSharedPreferenceChange() is not triggered.

That's why I refresh all preferences afterwards with this code:

```
private void refreshPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    for(int i = 0; i < getPreferenceScreen().getPreferenceCount(); i++) {
        onSharedPreferenceChanged(sp, getPreferenceScreen().getPreference(i).getKey());
    }
}
```

It works perfectly. I just wonder if a system call to invalidate all preferences exists that would achieve the same result (an automatic call to onSharedPreferenceChanged() )

I am not anal, I am just not fond of manually calling methods that are supposed to be called by the OS.

**Edit**
This is my current code that changes a preference. I tried before to change with editor but was also not generating onSharePreferncesChanged() calls.
source: it's a multiline string that was read from a file

```
private enum Type { INT, BOOLEAN, EDITTEXT, LIST }; 

private void loadPreference(int key, char [] source, Type t) {
    String s = new String(source);
    Log.i(TAG, "+ loadPreference(key:" + key + ", source:(" + s + "), t:" + t + ")");
    String sKey = getText(key).toString();
    Matcher m;
    Preference p = findPreference(sKey);
    switch( t ) {
    case BOOLEAN:
        m = Pattern.compile("(?m)^" + sKey + "=\"(true|false)\"$").matcher(s);
        if( m.find() ) ((CheckBoxPreference)p).setChecked(m.group(1).equals("true"));
        break;
    case INT:
        m = Pattern.compile("(?m)^" + sKey + "=\"(\\d+)\"$").matcher(s);
        if( m.find() ) ((EditTextPreference)p).setText(m.group(1));
        break;
    case EDITTEXT:
        m = Pattern.compile("(?m)^" + sKey + "=\"(.*)\"$").matcher(s);
        if( m.find() ) ((EditTextPreference)p).setText(m.group(1));
        break;
    case LIST:
        m = Pattern.compile("(?m)^" + sKey + "=\"(\\d+)\"$").matcher(s);
        if( m.find() ) ((ListPreference)p).setValueIndex(Integer.valueOf(m.group(1)));
        break;
    default:
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "- loadPreference()");
}

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
    Log.i(TAG, "+ onSharedPreferenceChanged(prefs:" + prefs + ", key:" + key + ")");
    if( key != null ) {
        updatePreference(prefs, key);
        updateSummary(findPreference(key));
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Preference without key!");
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "- onSharedPreferenceChanged()");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.i(TAG, "+ onResume()");
    super.onResume();
    // Set up a listener
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    Log.i(TAG, "- onResume()");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    Log.i(TAG, "+ onPause()");
    super.onPause();
    // Unregister the listener
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    Log.i(TAG, "- onPause()");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The guideline-compliant way to achieve this is to use an [`OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html).

In point 4 of your question, you say

> Because I change the vaules programatically,
>   onSharedPreferenceChange() is not triggered.

This depends on *how* you change the settings. In your point 2, you say

> For each setting I found there I extract the value and update the
>   corresponding preference...

Please make sure that you use the settings editor and *commit* your changes, similar to this:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("key","value"); // your updated setting
editor.commit();
```

If your other class properly implements an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` and has registered it by calling `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)` on your default `SharedPreferences`, you should be able to listen for these changes in the `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` method.

At least that's what the article in the [Dev Guide on Settings](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Listening) suggests and I have implemented it successfully in a similar way ("programmatically" changing settings).

**Updated answer:**
Since your comment says the above doesn't work, I had a look in my code again. Indeed, I got your question wrong by thinking you want to achieve this from a different class.

If you are in a `PreferenceFragment` (or `PreferenceActivity`), you can *also* implement the `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` interface, but register it for the preferences displayed in your current `PreferenceScreen`. Best practice would be to register it in `onResume()` by calling

```
getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

and then unregister in `onPause()`:

```
getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

As described previously, you receive the preference changes in `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` of your `PreferenceFragment` then. This is (now for real) the way it works in my code.

Comment: @saschaoar All your points are already done the way the guide recommends. If you have done something similar, you'll know that after `editor().commit` the preference views are NOT updated and the listener is NOT called. That's the whole point of the question I made, I want to trigger a listener call without doing it explicitly.

Comment: @saschaoar You probably missed the fact that I do all the changes while the preference screen is in view. In any other scenario ther is no problem at all, because the preference views are updated on entry to the preference screen.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer. Hope this does the trick. Besides, I'm aware that the editor commit does not update the views in your case (but it might have been the source of error). However, you say that you change your settings (programmatically), the change itself should already trigger the listener call, according to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html).

Comment: Do you catch calls to `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` ? Which target are you compiling to (mine is android-17 and I don't get any such call). ::: (BTW thanks for all the effort you are putting in answering my question)

Comment: I also target SDK version 17. It works perfectly, I'm using `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` to modify the pref summary after it has been changed. If you don't want to let your `PreferenceFragment` implement the listener, you may as well create it separately, like in this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8663800/1140682).

Comment: I posted my code in the question, maybe you have better eyes than I and can spot why onSharedPreferenceChanged() is not called when a preference is changed. ::: I remind you that I already tried using editor() instead of preferences and it was the same.

Comment: Thanks ;) Ok, so you let your `PreferenceFragment` implement the listener, correct? And: where and how do you register that listener, can you show that part of your code?

Answer (score 1):

OnSharedPreferencesChangeListener is not triggered when the new value is equal to the previous value. In this case SharedPreferences is not updated.

I worked around this clearing the old value when appropriate.